# Creating new queue for multiprocessing in python

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have a function that calculates planar values from lidar data. One argument that has influence is the neighborhood radius.I am using multiprocessing to run this function several time with different radius. I want to try many neighborhood radius and calculate the values. Right now when i pass the radius i have to create a new variable queue and get the result and join the process.

```
def calculate_planarity(lidar_data, neighborhood_radius, output_queue, tree):
    planarity_values = np.zeros(len(lidar_data))

    try:
        for point_idx, point in tqdm(enumerate(lidar_data), total=len(lidar_data), desc="Computing planarity"):
            neighbor_indices = tree.query_ball_point(point, neighborhood_radius)
            neighbors = lidar_data[neighbor_indices]

            if neighbors.shape[0] >= 3:
                cov_matrix = np.cov(neighbors, rowvar=False)
                eigenvalues, _ = np.linalg.eig(cov_matrix)
                sorted_eigenvalues = np.sort(eigenvalues)

                planarity = (sorted_eigenvalues[1] - sorted_eigenvalues[0]) / (
                            sorted_eigenvalues[0] + sorted_eigenvalues[1] + sorted_eigenvalues[2])
                planarity_values[point_idx] = planarity
            else:
                planarity_values[point_idx] = np.nan
    except Exception as e:
        print(f" An error occured in calculate_planarity: {e}")
        raise

    result = planarity_values
    output_queue.put(result)

if __name__ == "__main__":  
        planarity_queue = Queue()
        planarity_values = Process(target=calculate_planarity, args=(inPoints, 1, planarity_queue, tree,))
        planarity_values.start()
        
        planarity_queue3 = Queue()
        planarity_values3 = Process(target=calculate_planarity, args=(inPoints, 3, planarity_queue3, tree,))
        planarity_values3.start()
        
        planarity_queue10 = Queue()
        planarity_values10 = Process(target=calculate_planarity, args=(inPoints, 10, planarity_queue10, tree,))
        planarity_values10.start()

        planarity_result = planarity_queue.get()
        planarity_result3 = planarity_queue3.get()
        planarity_result10 = planarity_queue10.get()


        planarity_values.join()
        planarity_values3.join()
        planarity_values10.join()
```

Is it possible to just pass a list of radius and run these in parallel.I want to be able to just pass a list and not create new variable.

Comment: Please update your question with the correct indentation. I *could* guess at the correct indentation, but I could easily be wrong.

Comment: Do the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442910/how-to-use-multiprocessing-pool-map-with-multiple-arguments) help at all?